# How do I use a shared library in a static library

Tags: c++, android-ndk, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

My Android mk:

a.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := helloa

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloa.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

b.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hellob

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellob.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= helloa

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

c.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := helloc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloc.c

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := hellob

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and then I load shared libraries:

```
    System.loadLibrary("helloa");

    System.loadLibrary("helloc");
```

when the application called the java native interface, an error about "libc" occurred. the error is

"fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at 0x00000000 (code=1)"

when I changed the helloa module to a static library, and in hellob module used the static libraries. it worked well.

so I doubt that if the application can find the function entry address of java native interface when load two shared libraries.

This is the detailed error:

---

```
11-07 14:55:24.387: I/DEBUG(132): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-07 14:55:24.387: I/DEBUG(132): Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/P6-U06/hwp6-u06:4.2.2/HuaweiP6-U06/C17B116SP01:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'

11-07 14:55:24.387: I/DEBUG(132): Revision: '0'

11-07 14:55:24.387: I/DEBUG(132): pid: 11729, tid: 11729, name: a.xianmoyaoCMCC  >>> com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC <<<

11-07 14:55:24.387: I/DEBUG(132): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132): backtrace:

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):     #00  pc 0059c338  /mnt/asec/com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC-1/lib/libxianmoyao.so

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):     #01  pc 0059c4cd  /mnt/asec/com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC-1/lib/libxianmoyao.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::jstring2string(_jstring*)+24)

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132): stack:

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868560  400f8f44  

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868564  400d6b77  /system/bin/linker

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868568  00000006  

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be86856c  400e62d8  

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868570  400e2dbb  /system/bin/linker

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868574  400d6b3d  /system/bin/linker

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868578  5a0be478  

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be86857c  400d6ec3  /system/bin/linker

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868580  412eba30  [heap]

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868584  41f17dd8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868588  00000001  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be86858c  ffffffff  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868590  00000000  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868594  af17352c  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be868598  df0027ad  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be86859c  00000000  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):     #00  be8685a0  410dfde0  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685a4  be8685dc  [stack]

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685a8  41de7a08  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685ac  5e16e4d1  /mnt/asec/com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC-1/lib/libxianmoyao.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::jstring2string(_jstring*)+28)

11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):     #01  be8685b0  411e1879  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685b4  411e1858  
11-07 14:55:24.577: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685b8  0000002f  
11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685bc  5a0bee28  
11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685c0  00000000  

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685c4  5d5fd590  /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685c8  56f8f178  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685cc  40052010  

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685d0  00000000  

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685d4  5e16d90b  /mnt/asec/com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC-1/lib/libxianmoyao.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxHelper_nativeSetApkPath+10)

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685d8  412eba30  [heap]

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685dc  41f17ab8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685e0  41de7a08  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685e4  407c7514  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685e8  410dfda4  

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132):          be8685ec  00000001  

11-07 14:55:24.581: I/DEBUG(132): memory near r1:

11-07 14:55:24.764: I/BootReceiver(480): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)

11-07 14:55:24.787: I/WindowState(480): WIN DEATH: Window{42b20168 u0 com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC/com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC.XianMoYaoActivity}

11-07 14:55:24.787: I/ActivityManager(480): Process com.ppsea.xianmoyaoCMCC (pid 11729) has died.
```

the error is can not call Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxHelper_nativeSetApkPath.

Comment: Might be just a typo but, "LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := hello" should be "hellob" I guess.

Comment: this is not the problem. I made an error to describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES for a STATIC_LIBRARY has no effect. You must list all relevant shared libraries for `helloc` module, even if they are *inherited* from some static lib that `helloc` uses.

Comment: when I add a shared library “helloa” module in “helloc” module. the result is the same to my description. Maybe there is no error in this   construction.

Comment: You probably get a stack trace of the SIGSEGV. Using `addr2line` you can find what line of your code caused the problem.

Comment: now the problem is that can not find the true address of the native function. when call the native function, the sigsegv error  
occur. but when make it as a single shared library, it can find the true address. so I doubt that when load two shared library, the app can not make sure which library is the right library have the native

Comment: *can not find the true address of the native function* what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that when call the java native interface, the app can not find the function enter address. So a sigsegv error occurred. I am not sure if the java native interface can work well when load two shared libraries.

Comment: JNI works fine across multiple shared libraries. Check what `nm -D` says about libhelloc.so in the two cases.

Comment: thanks you so much. but I still have no clue to deal with it. could you introduce me a bloc that describe how to use shared libraries.

Comment: There is nothing special, so there probably is some simple mistake in your code. I would be glad to help, but I need more information. Did you compare the output of `nm -D` command?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know the nm -D command. But when I Generate all the source into a shared library（consist of several static library）, it worked well.

Comment: thank you very much, I have found the problem. I make a mistake that I forgot to compile a file with JNI_OnLoad();